# how to create XML using fetch data from database

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fetching data from database and send response in XML like below..

I want to fetch data into array or hash and then response to xml.... OR create direct xml..

Please refer below xml example...

```
<Response>
    <Tolls>
        <Toll>
            <Id>123</Id>
            <Name>Bradfield Highway</Name>
            <Address>Bradfield Highway, New York</Address>
            <Charge>5.95</Charge>
            <Location lat="41.145556" lng="-73.995"/>
               <EntryRects>
                 <EntryRect>
                   <Points>
                      <Point lat="41.145556" lng="-73.995"/>
                      <Point lat="41.145556" lng="-73.995"/>
                      <Point lat="41.145556" lng="-73.995"/>
                      <Point lat="41.145556" lng="-73.995"/>
                   </Points>
                 </EntryRects>
                 ...
               </EntryRects>
         </Toll>
        <Toll>
            ...
        </Toll>
        ...
    </Tolls>
</Response>
```

please send me response asap if any one know...

Comment: Do these XML tags correspond to attributes in a rails model?

Comment: Not neccessory, you can add new tag or use same as a database field

Comment: You have to provide us more information: what have you tried? Do you have corresponding models?

Comment: I want to fetch data from database and create XML like above example.

Comment: "`please send me response asap if any one know...`" It is unnecessary to ask for a response, especially one that is "ASAP". Please understand, we don't get paid, and we answer in our free time. We do this because we like to help.

Comment: yes, right the tin man.. sorry.. i will remember for future....

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [Builder::XmlMarkup](http://builder.rubyforge.org/), which provides a simple way to create XML markup and data structures

Comment: Thanks, but do not want to use any gem or lib. i want to create first array OR hash then want to convert XML.. any way..???

Comment: Why not? it handles complex stuff for you (scape sequences, etc)

Comment: Generating XML is NOT something you want to do by yourself, without aid from something else, because the spec is very rigid, and you will end up writing a lot of code replicating many other well-tested wheels.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what database you are using, but many can generate the XML for you as the result of a query, instead of returning a normal "select" statement's output. That would be the fastest/easiest path because the data is going to have to be returned to your app anyway, so let the DBM do the conversion on the fly.

Second easiest is to use something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), Builder or one of several other gems. They can handle the encoding of non-ASCII characters, specifying the correct headers, and make sure the nesting and tag closure is correct. That's why people use those tools, because they save a huge amount of coding.

The last choice should be attempting to do it yourself. Simply because you asked the question, I suspect you don't really understand what goes into creating well-formed XML. It's possible to generate trivial XML output using something like ERB or *maybe* HAML to help with the nesting, but encoding will fall directly on you. If you insist on doing it, then start reading all the related links on the right side of the Stack Overflow page, plus any XML documentation you can find.